# Arithmetic opertions using Convert.toInt32 and toString problems in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to do this but it returns 1024 no matter what value x is.

```
(Convert.ToInt32(x) * 1024).ToString()
```

This line is embedded in some razor code:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.AccountInfoModel.DiskSpace,
    Html.DropDownListFromComplexMember(m => m.AccountInfoModel.DiskSpace)
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = (Convert.ToInt32(x) * 1024).ToString(),
            Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x) * 1024).ToString()
        }))
```

Since it's a lambda expression embeded in another lambda expression, I can't pull the value and do the calculation outside the line.

Any ideas?

Comment: `(Convert.ToInt32(32) * 1024).ToString()` returns 32768 as expected. Not sure what "no matter what value x is" refers to...

Comment: my recommendation is to do this in the action method and pass values to the view via your Model

Comment: If `x` is a `string`, then you can just use `int.Parse(x)`.

Comment: Are you sure that the input format is correct at the point of the `Split` call? For your code, it should be `<int (as string)>,<next element>,...`

Comment: I'm not sure what `Html.DropDownListFromComplexMember` does, but it looks as if you're doing the split and the subsequent select on its result rather than on your model's property.  That might have something to do with it.

Comment: I couldn't fix the problem but I think Shyju is right, I moved the calculation to my controller, since doing this in the view is bad design.